# Bootstrap scrollspy not working in mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design, scrollspy

I am working on the site: http://indraply.in
The scrollspy is working fine on desktop but when I run the site on smaller devices like mobile, it doesn't run. 
**HTML CODE**

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
   <div class="loading"><p>WELCOME TO THE WORLD OF PLYWOOD</p></div>
   <a id="home"></a>
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
     <div class="container-fluid">
     <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
       <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
       </div>

       <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active">
               <a href="#home" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">HOME<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">ABOUT US</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#products">OUR PRODUCTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#brands">OUR BRANDS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#gallery">GALLERY</a></li> 
           </ul>
   </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
 </nav>
```

**SCROLLSPY JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Add scrollspy to <body>
    $('body').scrollspy({target: ".navbar", offset: 50});
    // Add smooth scrolling on all links inside the navbar
    $("#myNavbar a").on('click', function(event) {
        // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
        if (this.hash !== "") {
            // Prevent default anchor click behavior
            event.preventDefault();

            // Store hash
            var hash = this.hash;

            // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
            // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
            }, 1000, function(){

                // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
                window.location.hash = hash;
            });
        }  // End if

    });
});
</script>
```

Any solutions?

Comment: add your code so that we can help

Comment: Done. @neophyte

Comment: @AnmolWassan How was you solved this?  can you please help any me? I have face same issue as you here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74783384/react-bootstrap-scrollspy-active-link-not-working-in-android-mobile-browser