# React Bootstrap Scrollspy active link not working in Android mobile browser

Tags: android, html, reactjs, react-native, bootstrap-5

I have using **bootstrap 5.2.2** in **React** and implement Scrollspy functionality in menu.

Scrollspy is working fine in Web(Laptop) browser. also, It is working fine in iPhone mobile. **but, Scrollspy updates active link not working in Android Mobile.**

Live site here: [https://rutvik.online](https://rutvik.online/)

Can someone check out my page and see if they can determine what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a browser support issue rather than OS compatibility, because it works fine on Safari, Firefox and Edge, but not on Brave or DuckDuckGo.

Edit:

I actually had the same problem until I downgraded to Bootstrap 5.1.3 (from npm), importing scrollspy this way:

```js
import "bootstrap/js/src/scrollspy.js";

document.body.setAttribute("data-bs-spy", "scroll");
document.body.setAttribute("data-bs-target", "#scrollspy-nav");
document.body.setAttribute("data-bs-offset", "150");
```

Scrollspy has been rewritten to use the Intersection Observer API, which I believe is the reason why this is an issue in Bootstrap 5.2.x, but I don't have time right now to look into it.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/migration/#additional-changes